# Calling JS function from external file give error in yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I'm trying to call a JS function in a yii2 project but got function not define, 
the JS function is inside a file named main.js which is included to the layout of the homepage, and in site/index in have another internal JS code that calls the function in main.js file. if i put this function in site/index everything works fine as expected but if i separate it to call it from outside it says function not define.

My action page site/index:

```
<?php
 $getcatUrl = Yii::$app->UrlManager->createUrl(['site/getcategories']);

$script = <<< JS

 $(document).ready(function(){

       $(".sideBarNav").mouseenter(function(){
          id = $(this).attr('href');
          getCategories(id);
           $('.cat-container').css('display', 'block');
       });
  });
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Now in my main JS file i have the following:

```
  function getCategories(id){
           $.ajax({
                        url: '{$getcatUrl}',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {category_id: id},
            success: function (data) { 
                         data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                         //console.log(data); return;
                      if (data.length > 0) {
                        $("#dl-cat").html("");
                        var content = $("#dl-cat");
                        firstdata = data[0];
                        secdata = data[1];

                        for (var i = 0; i < firstdata.length; i++) {
                         // var d =  $( document.createElement('dl') );
                          var dl = $("<dl></dl>");
                          dl.append("<a href='"+firstdata[i].id+"'><dt>"+firstdata[i].name+"</dt></a>");

                              for (var j = 0; j < secdata.length; j++) {
                            if (secdata[i][j] !== undefined) {
                              dl.append("<dd><a href = '"+secdata[i][j].id+"'>"+secdata[i][j].name+"</a></dd>");
                            }

                          }
                        content.append(dl);
                        }

                      } else {
                        console.log('no item for this categories');
                      }
                   },
                error: function(jqXHR, errMsg) {
                 // handle error
                    console.log(errMsg);
                }
            });
       }
```

Note other codes from the JS file works expect from functions that needed to be called from external source
This how do i solve this problem any help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet, the script is before the jquery all, so the function "disappears". Try placing the script in a external file and making sure that

try «I hope it helps»

```
    $this->registerJsFile(
        '@web/js/your_file.js',
        ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::class]]
    );
```

If it's not exactly this, but probably the function is being placed after the call, so it will be undefined, so try to be sure that the function gets rendered before the call.

Comment: thanks for your help but i include the JS file in the app asset file, and it renders to all page that uses the layout, or do i need to do this separately in each page i need to use the JS file to ensure proper rendering? if so where do I include it, thanks so much

Comment: Well you might use it on the asset file, or on your php view, but just be sure that the function is before the call, if not it will fail. javascript needs the function to exist before its being used, and it runs sequentially, so if the call runs first, it will run into the undefined error.

Comment: Try the following, render jquery in the header. Add  `public  $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];`  into AppAsset.php. This is not a good practice but it will make my point if your code is being executed before jquery loads. If what I believe its happening, then your code will run.

Comment: @ moplin thanks a lot from your explanation i was able to make it work, the actual issue was that i put the function in $(document).ready(function(){}); so it waited until the DOM is loaded before it fires but the call to it has already loaded, so got undefined, thanks alot i will accept your answer